# How to do a single delete and bulk delete action in wp_list_table in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, delete-row, recycle-bin

I am displaying custom data in wp_list_table. I was able to display the data correctly in the table. Now I want to add this functionality: when I click on the delete button by hovering on the row or else selecting the checkbox for multiple deletes, I want to move items to trash. When permanently deleting an item, that row should be deleted from the table. How can I achieve this? I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Always use the id for the entry in your view to enable edits.

Use the id to delete single or multiple entries of your data. 

Track the 'delete'-click and use

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id IN($ids)");
```

For details see [two issues](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76374/wp-list-tables-bulk-actions) on stack exchange for further information.
[Really detailed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265648/wp-list-table-bulk-action-get-edit-and-delete) about the necessary parts.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the path /wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php
Check file find function bulk_actions() all

Comment: Checked it, but not found exact solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

for guys like me who stumbled on this page for the same question, after a little search I found out that the code for trash & delete permanently actions,is splitted between two files:

- wp_{}_list_table.php => handles the request
- edit.php => handles action